# the websocket auto disconnect with 1005 and 1006 code

Tags: node.js, nginx, websocket

Now I found some websocket could not enstablished the connection(some websocket works fine, some websocket auto disconnect), the server capture the error code 1005 without other information. This is the code how to capture the code:

```
conn.on('close', (e) => {
    logger.warn('trigger close event', e)
    closeConn(doc, conn)
    clearInterval(pingInterval)
  })
```

the log output like this:

```
[WARN] default - trigger close event 1005
```

all websocket connections works fine but one facing the issue. I have searching and told that the nginx `proxy_read_timeout` configuration issue. This is my nginx configuration look like:

```
server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  ws.example.top;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example/privkey.pem;

    if ($allowed = 0) {
        return 403;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP 192.210.203.237;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

the server side using node version 16.20.2 and `"ws": "^6.2.1"`.